# Subtotal + Vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to fill in these 2 cells with a formula.
Normally Id filter country for Canada and run a subtotal below.
with something like this `=SUBTOTAL(9,J4:J8)`

How can I combine a vlookup into my subtotal with subtotalling filtered countries?

[image]

[image]

[image]

expected output -
[image]

thanks.

Comment: SUMIF would produce these totals easily, but will not respect any filters or hidden rows applied. But if feels like you would want these headline figures to be the same regardless of filtering by country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what you're asking. I would be default assume something like SUMIF or SUMIFS would do what you're looking for.

[image]

Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: If you're unsure what the user is asking for, why not add a comment to the original question seeking clarification?

Comment: Because I wanted to see if this is what they were looking for and you can't post an image in comments.